# Double map region

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, latitude-longitude

I'm getting the visible map region using

```
LatLngBounds region = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
```

Is there a way I can double or add to this region by code?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [LatLngBounds.including](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds#including%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng%29):

```
LatLngBounds biggerRegion = region.including(new LatLng(...));
```

Comment: How would I know what LatLngs to add to get a bigger region though? Can I just add some number to the latitude?

Comment: @GrayStatic If you calculate the difference between original region's min and max latitude, you can use that value to add to north latitude and subtract from south.

Comment: Honestly my first time working with maps and cordinates. At the moment I'm adding markers in the visible region which works fine but I also remove those that aren't in the visible region which also works fine. The result however is that user can see the markers being removed and replaced. I just want to increase region for removal. Is there a straight forward method to achieve this?